# piping in UNIX doubt

Tags: unix, piping

In The Unix Programming Environment by K & P, it is written that
" The programs in a pipeline actually run at the same time, not one after another.
This means that programs in a pipeline can be interactive;"

How can programs run at same time?
For ex: $ who | grep mary | wc -l
How grep mary will be executed until who is run or how wc -l will be executed until it 
knows results of previous programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- All three programs will start. grep and wc wait for input via stdin
- `who` will output a line of data, which `grep` will then receive
- If the line matches, grep will write it to `stdout`, which `wc` will then read and count
- In the meantime, `who` may also have been writing out more data for `grep` etc

Each program needs the results of the previous one, but it doesn't need *all* of the results before it can *start* working, which is why pipelining is feasible.